# Strong Name Validation Failed

Tags: windows-7

I recently migrated my OS to a new SSD hard disk.  Fresh install: Win 7

Ever since, I will get constant System.IO.FileLoadExceptions (Strong Name Validation Failed) which forces me to reinstall VS2008, SQL server,etc. every day or so.

A reinstall of the program in question will fix the problem for a few days, but then something else will "crack" and require a reinstall. It's almost as if the files on the disk get altered after a few days. I wonder if it is a HDD problem , an OS, or a combination of the two.

Incredibly anoying to arrive at work each morning not knowing what component has failed and will need a reinstall .

Any ideeas how I can further troubleshoot this ?

**Later edit:**
OK, this is getting out of hand.

I need to re-install up to 3 - 4 applications per day. I suspect there is something terribly wrong with my SSD HDD but any diskcheck reports the HDD is in order. Anyone knows of a good HDD check utility? Ideally something that will write/read many times over the same areas of a HDD and report inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Assembly Binding Log Viewer (Fuslogvw.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx) :

> The Assembly Binding Log Viewer
>   displays details for failed assembly
>   binds. This information helps you
>   diagnose why the .NET Framework cannot
>   locate an assembly at run time. These
>   failures are usually the result of an
>   assembly deployed to the wrong
>   location or a mismatch in version
>   numbers or cultures. The common
>   language runtime's failure to locate
>   an assembly typically shows up as a
>   TypeLoadException in your application.

See also [Suzanne Cook's .NET CLR Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) about "Debugging Assembly Loading Failures".

And lastly, see:
[We Were Crashing, DLLs Were Missing, Fusion Log Didn't Help... Now What!?](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2007/12/we-were-crashin.html)

Without seeing any of the data that can be retrieved using the above tools, Microsoft's [Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.IO.FileLoadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbe81ttk%28VS.80%29.aspx) defines "A FileLoadException exception is
thrown when a managed assembly is
found but cannot be loaded". I would therefore first try to uninstall and then reinstall all the .Net Frameworks on your machine.

And regarding hard disk test programs, the best I know is [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm), at $ 89 with Absolute Satisfaction Guarantee no-questions refund policy.

Answer (score 0):

Every time this has happened to me, it was either bad RAM or the fact that Dual Channel was turned on when either the RAM or the motherboard didn't really support it. In both of these cases, random corruption occured.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of research, the error you posted seems to be related with problems on .net and software related rather than hardware.

Do you have any software on that is meant to help / fix / extend or do anything out the normal in relation to .net?

Are the programs that all require reinstalling .net based?

You may not like this, but I would reinstall Windows from scratch then install your Visual Studio + Sql however it is you do it and not install anything non Microsoft or third party you do not trust, wait a couple of days and see if you get the same problem.

If you do from installing no other utilities, I think it is a hardware problem, either something on your motherboard, bad memory or the hard drive. IF you do install other utilities and still get the error, please post here what programs you installed.

Comment: Well, about 90% of the problems are from .net programs. But I think that's just because they do this strong name validation thingie, which is more succeptible to the data corruption that occurs on my disk. As far as I know, the corruption occurs on all programs, it's just that those other programs simply "keep on running" as best as they can (still crashing ocasionally though)

Comment: I still advise you try what I said and reinstall Windows - Only by clearing everything and starting from scratch will you know if it was a software based error caused by something or an actual hardware error as this should persist through whatever operating system you install. However, the fact that it is 90% .net programs just says to me this is a software error as I am surprised it hasn't *hit* a system file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a interesting problem - there are 2 good articles that explain how this works:http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/28/strongnaming.html and http://www.grimes.demon.co.uk/workshops/secWSThree.htm. I think if you have a backup of the SSD I would try the reinstall option to see if the problem goes away. The issue seems to be the hash calculated at load does not match what is expected and I could see that your SSD could indeed be the culprit but see no easy way to confirm that. The variant being what tool was used to move your OS over to the SSD. Is there any info from the manufacturer of your SSD that indicates this is a known issue? I haven't seen any articles suggesting this is a common issue with SSDs which suggests the reinstall idea is a good way to eliminate the variant of the OS transfer. I'd be really interested to see what the solution is.

Comment: I should point out that all of these answers assume the obvious has been eliminated. That is the assemblies are not actually being altered by something like a virus.